# which youtube url modifier to use to enforce mobile version on a desktop pc

Tags: html, url, mobile, youtube, url-modification

I remember I saw somewhere on the internet a way to use url modifiers to set mobile version of YouTube permanently - until the current tab with that url is closed.

I tried searching here, but don't see anything similar.
It was something like
`https://youtube.com/?app_force_m=1` or `https://youtube.com/?mobile_force`

or `https://youtube.com/?force_version=mobile_app`

Trying to use my intuition, but too hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the mobile version use: https://m.youtube.com/?persist_app=1&app=m

Or perhaps you want a direct embed of the video? https://www.youtube.com/embed/dX3k_QDnzHE

Comment: those children use psychokinesis without empathy technique, only visualization...Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: and is there any way to pass UA strings as url modifiers to switch between temporary UA: `desktop firefox to desktop IE11` , `desktop chrome to iPad safari`  ?

Comment: Not that I know of, you can change the user agent via your browser if needed; e.g. in Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg